# What are some good usability addins for Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, user-interface, tabs

I've been using Visual Studio for a long time and the constant shuffling of the code tabs at the top drives me bonkers. I was wondering if there were any add-ins that might change this or other UI behavior.

Things that might be cool:

- Sticky Tabs that won't go away.
- Multi-code file collapsible tabs (maybe each tab being a project?).
- <s>Having the solution tree go to the file you are currently looking at automatically.</s> Thanks Omlette!
- Your idea here.

I've done a bit of googling and haven't been able to find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rick,

[Tabs Studio](http://www.tabsstudio.com) add-in for Visual Studio is a replacement for built-in tabs. Multiple rows of tabs make them always visible. Tabs can be grouped, it is probably close to what you call "multi-code file tabs".

See [Tabs Studio home page](http://www.tabsstudio.com) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

The "Having the solution tree go to the file you are currently looking at automatically" feature already exists in VS2008, but isn't enabled by default.  Go to tools -> options -> projects and solutions -> general and check the "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer" box.

Comment: Ahh awesome, now if I had sticky tabs I would be completely set.